# Angular 2 viewChild with ngForm causing compilation errors

Tags: angular

I have this component, which I have stripped down as far as possible to still get the same error:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reply-box',
  template: '<form #frm="ngForm"></form>'
})
export class ReplyBoxComponent {
  @ViewChild("frm", { static: false }) form: NgForm;
  constructor() {}
}
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Expecting flags [Expected=> number === boolean <=Actual]
    Angular 3
    ReplyBoxComponent_Query main.js:1527
```

main.js:1527 is:
`_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ɵɵviewQuery"](_c0, true);`

I have:

- Deleted and reinstalled node-modules
- Upgraded all dependencies

If I comment out the `@ViewChild` line, everything works fine.

If I set `static: true`, I get a different error of

```
ERROR in ./src/app/Shared/comment-section/reply-box/reply-box.component.ts 72:8-28
"export 'ɵɵstaticViewQuery' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
```

`ng version` info:

```
Angular: 11.2.14
... animations, common, core, forms, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.15
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.15
@angular/cdk                    12.2.12
@angular/cli                    11.2.15
@angular/compiler               9.1.13
@angular/compiler-cli           9.1.13
@schematics/angular             11.2.15
@schematics/update              0.1102.15
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      3.8.3
```

I feel as though I'm missing something obvious and would like input.

Comment: Are you sure all your packages are compatible with your Angular version  ?

Comment: There is quite a big version discrepancy between angular version and compiler version. That doesn’t look right. Did you do a manual update or something..? What happens if you run an ng update latest?

Comment: is it normal to have `@angular/cdk` in version 12 and `@angular-devkit/core` is in the 11 one ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading and synchronizing my angular package versions has fixed this issue.